# Method to recursively enable/disable buttons within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have a panel of buttons that I want to enable/disable with a single method call.  Generalize this to any kind of user input subtree of DOM nodes that you'd like to enable/disable.

Is there an existing or commonly-accepted best-practice to achieve this?  Or must I write my own in a fashion something like this:

```
var recursivelyDisable = function(node, shouldDisable) {
  // If there are no children, return
  if (???) return;

  // Grab the next child node

  // Recurse
  recursivelyEnable(childNode);

  // Apply the setting
  node.disabled = shouldDisable;
};
```

In `index.html`:

```
      <div id="my-controls" class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="row">
              <button id='a-toggle' type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Toggle A</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
              <button id='b-toggle' type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Toggle B</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
              <button id='c-toggle' type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Toggle C</button>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="row">
              <button id='d-toggle' type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Toggle D</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML. You shouldn't need recursion for this. Use a common class and something like `$('.button').prop('disabled', false);`

Comment: HTML added.  I really want to isolate by DOM node subtree through, not all of my buttons with class 'button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not stated what event you're running this under, but all the buttons within the `#my-container` element have a common class, so you could make a one-liner to enable/disable them:

```
$('#my-controls .btn').prop('disabled', true); // disable
$('#my-controls .btn').prop('disabled', false); // enable
```

Recursion is not needed here as jQuery will apply that property to all the elements matched by the selector.

Comment: There's an outer button, that I want to turn on/off everything within `my-controls`

Comment: Updated the answer for you, you just need to amend the selector as needed.

Comment: Some of my controls are sliders.  Is there an issue with applying the property to every sub node, and then it only having an affect on nodes that can do anything with the `disabled` property?

Comment: Yes, applying disabled on every sub node will make your HTML invalid. If you have sliders look in their documentation to see how to disable them.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$('.selector').find('button').prop('disabled', true);
```

The [find function](http://api.jquery.com/find/) should do what you need.

EDIT: As others have mentioned, it is probably a good idea to use a specific selector to accomplish this, as you may cause yourself some UI headaches later on if you need a specific button in a DOM node not to be disabled for some reason. Depending on your code structure, it may be easier to just generate buttons that can be disabled with this tag and select by that and save yourself the effort of having to explicitly undo the disable effect on a button that needs to stay functional and happens to live in the same node.